# packets dropping while trying to send video streaming using ffmpeg library via RTP cpp

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, sdp

I have a code of a streamer and a receiver written in cpp. I am trying to send packets that contain picture streaming from a video in the streamer (flv video) but in the receiver i get
[these errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6imjt.png)
.I have a sdp file in the receiver that contain the following data:

```
v=0
o=- 0 0 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=No name
t= 1 1000000
a=tool:libavformat 55.19.104
m=video 1234 RTP/AVP 117
c=IN IP4 127.0.0.1
b=AS:394
a=rtpmap:117 H264/90000
```

Does anyone know what is the cause of the problem and the best way to fix it?

Comment: [`RTP`](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3550#section-1) is usually implemented on top of `UDP` which doesn't guarantee anything with regards packet delivery.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is your only problem but the payload format for H.264 is "H264/90000"... the receiver may be seeing that as "90" instead.  A messed up clock rate could explain what you're seeing with missing and late packets.

Comment: Doesnt change anything... any other suggestions?